# Hide querystring parameter name from an URL generated with Html.ActionLink in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using Html.ActionLink to generate a link.

> @Html.ActionLink(item.Text, item.Author.UniqueName, "Author", new { selectedQuoteId = item.QuoteID }, null)

However when I use this method, the generated link is :

```
http://localhost/Author/aeschylus?selectedQuoteId=1627
```

But I would like it to be:

```
http://localhost/Author/aeschylus/1627
```

My configuration is:

> routes.MapRoute(
>                               "AuthorQuotes",
>                               "Author/{authorUniqueName}/{selectedQuoteId}",
>                               new
>                               {
>                                   controller = "AuthorQuotes",
>                                   action = "Index",
>                                   authorUniqueName =  UrlParameter.Optional,
>                                   selectedQuoteId = UrlParameter.Optional
>                               });

Is this possible to do this with Html.ActionLink ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you have placed this custom route **before** the default one. Also you seem to have forgotten to provide a value for the `authorUniqueName` portion of your route. Since this is not the last part of your route pattern, it cannot be optional.

So start by fixing your route definition:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "AuthorQuotes", 
    "Author/{authorUniqueName}/{selectedQuoteId}", 
    new { 
        controller = "AuthorQuotes", 
        action = "Index", 
        selectedQuoteId = UrlParameter.Optional 
    }
);
```

and then provide a value for this required parameter:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    item.Text, 
    item.Author.UniqueName, 
    "Author", 
    new { 
        authorUniqueName = item.Author.UniqueName,
        selectedQuoteId = item.QuoteID 
    }, 
    null
)
```

Basically if you want to have optional parameters in a route, this can only be the last one. If you need to have multiple optional parameters then use query strings (just as you had), otherwise the routing engine cannot disambiguate between them.

Comment: Another problem was that I was using "item.Author.UniqueName" instead of "index" as action. And "Author" instead of "AuthorQuotes" as controller. So I think the routing engine was just skipping my route and going straight to the default route after.